# Wall to wall carpeting over tile?

Tags: tile, carpet

## QUESTION

If a tenant wanted wall to wall carpeting and the existing floor is tile, is it possible to simply lay the padding and carpet over the tile, and expect the ability to revert back to the tile by simply removing the carpeting?

## TILE PHOTOS

IDK what category of tile this falls into (not ceramic):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of "tile"?  That's a pretty generic term.  "Simply laying" "Wall to wall" do you mean not attaching the way traditional carpet would be attached using tack strips?

Comment: @Tyson: Good questions: IDK, so I posted photos.  Seem like they are chemically made (vinyl-like).  It would be great if the tack strips could be deployed such that they can be removed in the future without a fuss.   I suspect  that if I refloor, I will have to sacrifice the existing tile